# Android Studio Error : Unknown Host 'service.gradle.org'

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I was working on a project on Android Studio 3.0 Beta 2 when suddenly i get the following error in my console:

```
Error:Unknown host 'service.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project
Learn about configuring HTTP proxies in Gradle
```

I haven't made any changes to my `gradle`. I have tried invalidating caches and restarting Android Studio to no avail. I have restarted my computer as well but still no luck.

What's causing this to show up and how can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I realized there was a typo and was supposed to be `services.gradle.com` instead of `service.gradle.com`. I don't know how this happened since the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file wasn't open but that was the issue.